# Initialize Object as member of another class

Tags: c++

I just want to understand the flow how it happens as am new to c++.

Let me elaborate my problem statement.

```
class test1 {
public:
    test1() {
        cout << " test1::constructor called" << endl;
    }
    ~test1() {
        cout << " test1::destrcutor called" << endl;
    }
};

class test2 {
public:
    test2() {
        cout << " test2::constructor called" << endl;
    }
    ~test2() {
        cout << " test2::destrcutor called" << endl;
    }
};

class derived :public test1, public test2 {
    test2 t2;
    test1 t1;
public:
    derived() {
        cout << " derived constructor called" << endl;
    }
    ~derived() {
        cout << "derived destructor called" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    derived d;
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program shows

```
   test1::constructor called
   test2::constructor called
   test2::constructor called
   test1::constructor called
   derived constructor called
   derived destructor called
   test1::destrcutor called
   test2::destrcutor called
   test2::destrcutor called
   test1::destrcutor called
```

So here my question is at what points it called the constructor of the member variables in derived class as I have not put any initializer for the same.

Comment: Since you are new to C++ one thing to be aware of when using inheritance and polymorphism is to make sure that classes you are deriving from you are using virtual destructors this will save you a lot of headaches in the future! Since derived is inheriting from both test1 & test2 both destructors in test1 & test2 should be virtual! It may not be necessary but it would be good practice to have your derived destructor virtual as well! This helps to keep the order in which objects get destroyed so that pointers in classes remain valid, especially when working with dynamic or new memory.

Answer (score 8):

The order of construction is bases, then members so :-

```
test1::constructor called  << first base of 'derived'
test2::constructor called  << second base of 'derived'
test2::constructor called  << member of 'derived' t2
test1::constructor called  << member of 'derived' t1
derived constructor called << code in 'derived::derived'
derived destructor called  << code in 'derived::~derived'
test1::destrcutor called   << destruction of t1
test2::destrcutor called   << destruction of t2
test2::destrcutor called   << destruction of derived
test1::destrcutor called   << destruction of derived
```

There is only one destructor of an object, and it has a defined order to destroy objects.  That is destroy all the members from bottom to top of the class.

Then destroy the class, and its bases in "reverse order".

Each constructor can choose what to initialize, but not the order.

```
a_class::a_class( params ) : 
           base_n( params ), base_n_1( params ), 
           member_1( params), member_2( params),...
```

This `member initialization list` allows different parameters to be given to construct all the bases and objects, but does not effect the order.  It is always `first_base`, `second_base`, `first_member`, `second_member`, ...

This ordering is to ensure it is the opposite of the destructor.

These rules allowed me to work out which message was from the members, and which from the bases.

A member which does not get initialized from the `member initialization list` will still get its default constructor called `test2::test2`.  As once a `class`/`struct` have a constructor, they will only come into existence by having a constructor called.

`Plain-old-Data` or `POD` are simple types such as `int` which don't have constructors.  They are left uninitialized (whatever values were left behind in the memory).